# Changing jquery cluetip dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I am trying to change the cluetip content dynamically by changing the title attribute dynamically as I am using the cluetip plugins splittitle method to generate the cluetip on a table row. I am using the jquery attr(key,value) method to change the title value but the title remains the same as the one which is loaded the first time the cluetip is generated. I checked the value of title by using jquery attr() getter method...which shows that the title has changed but firebug shows that the title has not been updated.
I was wondering if anybody came across such situation.
Any help regarding this would be great.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try setting: `ajaxCache: false`.